# Remove last matching element in an array that meets a condition

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm working on a Kata. Given a list `lst` and a number `N`, I am creating a new list that contains each element of `lst` at most `N` times without reordering. For example if `N = 2`, and the input is `[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3]`, I take `[1,2,3,1,2]`, drop the next `[1,2]` since this would lead to `1` and `2` being in the result 3 times, and then take `3`, which leads to `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`.

Here is my code:

```
def delete_nth(order,max_e)
  #your code here
  order.any? do |element| 
    if order.count(element) >  max_e
      order.delete_at(order.index(element)) 
    end
  end
  order
end
```

Here is the output.

> From array [20,37,20,21],1 you get - Expected: [20, 37, 21], instead
>   got: [37, 20, 21]

It erases the first element that meets that criteria in the array and I need to remove the last element.

Answer (score 3):

@Steenslag and @Stefan suggested the same improvement (though expressed differently) to my original answer. I've edited my answer to incorporate that improvement.

**Code**

```
def doit(arr, n)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  arr.select { |e| n >= h[e] += 1 }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3]
n = 2   
doit arr, n
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Explanation**

The steps performed for the values of `arr` and `n` in the example are as follows.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

This is the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a default value, here zero. All that means is that if `h` defined above does not have a key `k`, the default value is returned:

```
h['cat'] #=> 0
```

This does not change the hash. If we now write `h[:a] = 1` (so `h=>{:a=>1}`), then `h[:a]` returns `1` because `h` now has a key `:a`. Continuing,

```
enum = arr.reject
  # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]:reject>
```

The first value is generated by `enum` and passed to the block, and the block variable is assigned its value.

```
e = enum.next
  #=> 1
```

The block calculation is now performed

```
h[e] += 1
  #=> h[e] = h[e] + 1
  #   h[e] = 0 + 1 = 1
```

so now

```
h #=> { 1=>1 }
```

and because

```
2 >= h[1]
  #=> true
```

the first element of `arr` is selected.

There are two things to note about the expression `h[1] = h[1] + 1`. Firstly, because `h` does not have a key `1`, `h[1]` on the right of the equality returns the default value, zero. Secondly, the default value is used by the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), not by [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) (on the left of the equals sign).

The second value of `enum` is now passed to the block and similar calculations are performed.

```
e = enum.next
  #=> 2
h[e] += 1
  #=> h[2] = h[2] + 1
  #   h[2] = 0 + 1
h #=> {1=>1, 2=>1}
2 >= h[2]
  #=> true
```

So the second element of `arr` is also selected. Let's skip the next three elements generated by `enum`:

```
enum.next
  #=> 3
enum.next
  #=> 1
enum.next
  #=> 2
```

At this point

```
h = { 1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1 }
```

and the block has returned a truthy value for each of the first `5` elements generated by `enum`.

Next,

```
e = enum.next
  #=> 1
h[e] += 1
  #=> h[1] = h[1] + 1
  #   h[1] = 2 + 1
h #=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 3=>1}
2 >= h[1]
  #=> 2 >= 3 => false
```

so this value, `1` is not selected. The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: `arr.select{|e|  (h[e] += 1) <= n}`

Comment: `arr.reject { |e| n < h[e] += 1 }`

Comment: ...@Stefan. Your suggestions--mirror images of each other--have allowed me to make a substantial improvement to my answer.